# Link to Random Hot Stack Exchange Network Question

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hot-questions

I've seen a Wikipedia link before where it would take you to a random page.  I used this for a while as my home page, however the pages were too irrelevant and I went back to a search engine home page.  I think it would be cool to set my home page to show a random hot question in the Stack Exchange network.  Not sure if this is possible.  I could try to write something, but I'd honestly rather just use something by Stack Exchange or somebody else if it already exists.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [How to get the hot questions by some query?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252914)

Comment: see also: [How can I get a HOT network questions week digest?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239310/165773) (side note [here is why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266297/can-we-get-a-hot-network-questions-newsletter#comment863980_266297 "'Just think of it, this week newsletter advertizes a bunch of questions and several weeks later, these are deleted by moderators. Not good, ain't it'") this feature is not going to be official)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could always just go to https://stackexchange.com/ and click the first (or any other) link. Beyond that, I doubt this is a feature that <s>Stack Exchange</s> Stack Overflow is particularly likely to implement.

If you really want it, though, it's almost trivial to roll your own solution. I wrote [**a little userscript to do it**](https://gist.github.com/edcottrell/7f54f8070be1a972ecb9) in about 5 minutes. To use it:

- Install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) (if you use Chrome) or [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (if you use Firefox). You need one of these to be able to run userscripts.
- [**Click here**](https://gist.github.com/edcottrell/7f54f8070be1a972ecb9/raw/94a034d379965348c406aa917f3fcf3fcebe7029/randomSEHotLink.user.js) to install the userscript.
- Now, whenever you go to https://stackexchange.com/?random, you will be directed to a random hot question from the (currently 50) network questions displayed on the stackexchange.com home page.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I think this is exactly what I want it to do!  I've never heard of Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey, due to a lack of experience and necessity.  But it looks really cool.  Thanks again!